# __init - лишний аргумент в объявлении функции?

Tags: linux, c, функции

На днях просматривал исходный код линукса и наткнулся на такое объявление функции в файле *init/main.c*:

- `static int __init init_setup(char *str) {...}`

Не могу понять зачем здесь `__init`, ведь он очевидно лишний, а может быть это директива препроцессора?

Объясните пожалуйста почему такая функция компилируется и что означает этот параметр?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832114/what-does-init-mean-in-the-linux-kernel-code

Comment: Linux написан на C, если бы Линус увидел тег C++, он бы Вас четвертовал.

Comment: @ixSci Вы правы) Я в основном гуглю c++ поэтому по привычке вписал не тот тэг.

Comment: Это специальный макрос для помещения кода в определённую секцию объектного файла.

Comment: @0andriy Спасибо, напишите пожалуйста ответ чтобы я мог закрыть вопрос.

Comment: Какой-то странный вопрос. Неужели подсветка синтаксиса не показывает вам сразу что это макрос? Можно ведь и сразу перейти к объявлению этого макроса и посмотреть, во что он раскрывается.

Comment: @VTT, для того чтобы всё это работало нужно открыть файл в IDE, а не в простом редакторе, да ещё и IDE/дерево исходников настроить...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, JFYI:  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/__init

Comment: Мне лень. Переведите, что написано по ссылке, приведенной @demonplus.

Answer (score 3):

Отвечу сам.

**__init** это макрос, дающий подсказку кернелу что этот ресурс (здесь функция) используется только при загрузке, и память занятая им может быть освобождена после.

- `#define __init __section(.init.text) __cold notrace`

Comment: Здесь вы путаете причину и следствие: макрос используется для размещения кода в определённой секции (.init.text), а ядро при работе использует эту секцию только на этапе загрузки, после чего занятая память отдаётся в систему.